# nginx produces four times more traffic than node-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, traffic, http-proxy

we are using node-http-proxy for a while and it works fine. But as our system grows bigger, we want to move to nginx.

We consume about 100 request per second at the moment, which produce an outgoing traffic of about 1mb/s.

Our tests with nginx (same amount of requests, same backend servers and same responses) produce an outgoing traffic of about 4mb/s.
We checked the headers, because that could have been the only difference in the response, but the headers didn't change that much.

Does anyone have an idea what else could produce this traffic increase?

Thanks, Kim

EDIT:
We don't use clustering, they are just dumb reverse proxies. Requests from domain A go to server A, domain B to server B, ...
We did tests in our production environment, so the backend servers stayed the same during tests, just the proxies changed.

Comment: Do you use clustering? Do you use only 1 node process at the backend?

Comment: We do not use clustering, the proxies are used as simple reverse proxies. Requests from domain A go to server A, domain B to server B and so on.

Comment: By default, node uses 1 process but nginx is multi-core optimized, that could be one reason.

Comment: I would also have thought it can be the headers / cookies exchanges (with each request). By simply using Chrome console and tools, you can see the detailed exchange of a single request - try with node-http-proxy and nginx.

Comment: Do you have gzip turned on? I am guessing this is it ... Also is the body of the content the same?

Comment: gzip is turned of on both proxies and the content of the bodies is the same, too. We used "curl -i" on ubuntu to compare the headers and they are pretty much the same, except one or two lines.

Comment: If you have N threads/cores, you should have N or N-1 processes for NodeJS also, only that way you utilize the system fully.

Comment: Mustafa...could you please explain in which way the number of processes a proxy uses affects the amount of traffic returned to the client?

Comment: Simple, NodeJS uses only 1 core with 1 proecess. When Node is working, the other cores are doing otherwork. IF you spawn appropriate number of processes, all the cores are utilized for Node processes.

Comment: If the number of requests stays the same and incoming traffic stays the same, it doesn't matter how many workers process these requests. If a shop hires a second employe doesn't mean that there are more customers on a sudden ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out what happens: The old node.js server doesn't send all the required ssl certificates. The nginx sends all certificates (intermediate, etc.) with every request.